# Open-source Java library for HTML5 validation?

Tags: java, html

Is there any good open-source Java library for HTML5 validation? It would be great if it did CSS 3 validation too. JTidy has  not been maintained for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for both the W3C [HTML](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/markup-validator/file/tip/) and [CSS](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/2002/css-validator/) validators is available, though only the CSS one is written in Java.  The [repo for validator.nu is here](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/htmlparser/), that is written in Java.

However you should note that HTML5 validation is different to that for previous versions of HTML.  Previous versions of HTML depended on a DTD and followed an SGML validation model, HTML5 no longer has a DTD or any link to SGML.  It's possible that what you want is not an HTML5 validator, but [an HTML5 linter](http://lint.brihten.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I do want is a HTML5 linter. I wish there was a Java library, since I want to run a HTML5 linter in unit tests, in an environment where an outside internet connection may not be available.

Answer (score 1):

[validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) is open source. No CSS parsing though.

Answer (score 0):

Asking the same question myself, I see there is a project called `jcabi` which implements a *very* simple validation interface in Java.

http://w3c.jcabi.com

Very simple example based on their GIT readme:

```
import com.jcabi.w3c.HtmlValidator;
assert ValidatorBuilder
           .html()
           .validate("<html>hello!</html>")
           .valid()
           ;
```

It appears to check against a remote service (which seems like overkill depending on what you are doing), though you could install your own local instance.